# Cant ping my home router from remote 4g router

Tags: vpn, wireless-router, ping

first time to post here. I m trying to setup a VPN connection from a westermo 4g router thats at a remote site to my tp-link router vpn. But I have noticed that I can not even ping my vpn router from the westermo router while I can ping the vpn router from my laptop when on a different network also.

Any ideas why?

Comment: “But I have noticed that I can not even ping my vpn router from the westermo router while I can ping the vpn router from my laptop when on a different network also.” - Did you forward the port? Are you using your intranet IP address or Internet address? Are you perhaps behind a CGNAT?

Comment: Are you doing all pings through the internet? Perhaps a drawing of the schemata of both cases would give more information, including routers and networks and IP addresses (even partial ones).

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? There are a decent number of questions on this site alone about making a home network reachable from the public internet.